GRUB Does not detect Windows 11
Grub in ubuntu 24.04 does not see Windows 11, os-prober also does not find anything. Output of sudo fdisk -l: https://pastebin.com/0KTfUd9S
Windows is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p1, ubuntu on /dev/sda.
I've already tried, it seems, absolutely everything. I can log into Windows and Ubuntu by changing the startup priority in UEFI, but the Grub menu does not appear anywhere.

Does this answer your question? GRUB does not detect Windows

It does not look like you installed Windows per Microsoft's recommendation. You have a DOS (MBR) partitioned NVMe drive which means Windows is in old BIOS boot mode. Microsoft has recommended vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. Reinstall Windows. How you boot install media UEFI or old BIOS is then how it installs. UEFI & BIOS are too different, so once you start to boot, you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode as it is booted. Your grub is in UEFI boot mode, so cannot boot an old BIOS Windows.

Just noticed Windows says it is in a FAT32 partition. That is not an install as installs in BIOS mode have a smaller NTFS boot partition and a large NTFS as "c:drive" partition. Is that a Windows installer? But Windows installer has to be created from a Windows installer as the .wim file is over 4GB and that is not supported in FAT32. But FAT32 required for UEFI boot. Windows tools split the .wim file to fit.
